# How to add an existing library as a remote for a host in NX workspace?

Tags: reactjs, nx-workspace, nx-devkit

Is there a way to convert an existing app to become a host in NX workspace? When I run the command of generating a host with the name of an existing app it says:

> Specify a unique name for the project to allow Nx to differentiate
> between the two projects.

I also have a lot of libraries that I want to add them as remote for my host.
Is there anyway to do this or should I generate new remotes and copy and paste my codes and files in them ?

Comment: For angular, `nx g @nrwl/angular:setup-mf my-app --mfType=host` did the work of setting up existing app to host. Have you find the way to use existing library (having its own routing and logic) as a remote App ?

Comment: @SagunGautam No I haven't and also the command you mentioned is not available in the new version of Nx